# Android make a widget like Battery doctor

Tags: android, widget

I would like to make a widget like the one in the top left corner on this image :

http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Battery-Doctor-Android-Lockscreen.jpg

It's used by Battery Doctor to display the charging percentage                               I want to make the same with a variable that would change as soon as it changes in my background running application

Do you know how I could do that, some code, some tutorial ?

Comment: it's an android notification http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not a widget. It's just an status bar icon of app notification. To make same 'widget' each time you'll receive an intent about changing battery state you need have 100 pre-generated or custom drawable with different percentage and then generate new notification and set this image as `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.battery_percent_45)`. Here is useful [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPriority(int)).